# How to do embedded documents using spring java mongo repository

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have one document from sample_collection1 as

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5e597a2be08a070bab329ef3"
},
"field1": "value1",
"field2": [{
    "field3": "1234123",
    "field4": [{
        "field5": "3432",
        "field6": ["5e5ac0008def101ffa037100"
        ]
    }]
}]
```

}

and other document from sample_collection2 in one of the following type as

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e5ac0008def101ffa037100”},”childfield1”:”5e5ac0008def101ffa037906","childfield2”:”childvalue2”,"childfield3”:”childvalue3”}
```

or as

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e5ac0008def101ffa037906”},”childfield1”:” 5e5ac0008def101ffa037100","childfield2”:”childvalue2”,"childfield3”:”childvalue3”}
```

how to get following response using spring mongo repository

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5e597a2be08a070bab329ef3"
},
"field1": "value1",
"field2": [{
    "field3": "1234123",
    "field4": [{
        "field5": "3432",
        "field6": [{”childfield1”:”","childfield2”:”childvalue2”,"childfield3”:”childvalue3”}
        ]
    }]
}]
```

}

Comment: An aggregation query can be used. You can use the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) aggregation operator to "join" the two collections and get the _response_ output.

Comment: @prasad_ please provide mondb query or java code to lookup and replace existing nested id reference with documents from another collection